# Change a variable number for any class

Tags: jquery

I have a view classes ".st1, .st2, .st3, ..." and if I hover them I need to display the classes ".og1, .og2, .og3, ...". Right now only the first class ".st1" is working. How can I change the code that "count" is changing its number for "oG" too?

```
var sT = ".st",
    oG = ".og",
    count = Number();

$(sT + count).on("mouseover", function() {
    $(oG + count).show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(oG + count).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp when you use Number() it is always returning 0, so this is only working with stg0, if you will have multiple classes I would recommend you to have an array or something that tells you which number can be in the "stg" string. For example:

```
var numberList = [1,2,3];
var sT = ".st",
    oG = ".og"

for(let i = 0; i<numberList.length; i++)
{
  $(sT + i).on("

mouseover", function() {
    $(oG + i).show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(oG + i).hide();
});      
}
```

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 0):

Do not use incremental `class` or `id` attributes. They are an anti-pattern which make your code needlessly complicated and harder to maintain.

Instead, use the same common `class` on both groups of elements and relate them by index. Something like this:

```js
$('.st').hover(function() {
  $('.og').eq($(this).index()).toggle();
});
```

```css
.og { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="st">st #1</span>
  <span class="st">st #2</span>
  <span class="st">st #3</span>
  <span class="st">st #4</span>
  <span class="st">st #5</span>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="og">og #1</li>
  <li class="og">og #2</li>
  <li class="og">og #3</li>
  <li class="og">og #4</li>
  <li class="og">og #5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[class^='st']").on("mouseover", function() {
    var class = $(this).attr('class');
    var count = class.replace('st','');
    $(".og" + count).show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    var class = $(this).attr('class');
    var count = class.replace('st','');
    $(".og" + count).hide();
});
```